# Replace the slashes in string for file path

Tags: c#

I am getting data from a SQL table and using it to load html pages to my local hard disk. Some of the data from the server contains "\" so instead of going into the temp folder the name of the file looks like it is in a different folder. I get the following error.

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Customer\Referral-HP.html'.

How do I remove the forward slash from the name and\or replace it with an underscore.

```
var page = "Customer\Referral-HP";
var location = page; 
if (location.Contains("\\"))
{
    location = location.Replace("\\", "_"); 
}
var path = @"C:\temp\" + location + ".html";
```

I get `C:\temp\Customer\Referral-HP.html` but I am trying to get it to be  `C:\temp\Customer_Referral-HP.html` instead.

I am using the data I am getting from the database to create a file path, however, how do you handle invalid characters for a file path?

Comment: um that should be fine - why isn't it working?

Comment: So you want to change `Customer\Referral-HP.html` to `Customer_Referral-HP.html` ? do you have only one slash inside the filename or there could be more?

Comment: No, some of the data entries have more than one slash, for sure.

Comment: @ma3str0 what do you get when you try your code?

Comment: I get C:\temp\Customer\Referral-HP.html but I am trying to get C:\temp\Customer_Referral-HP.html

Comment: To try this out I changed the first line to `var location = "Customer\\Referral-HP";`, ran your code and I got `C:\temp\Customer_Referral-HP.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. However, there are more characters than just `\` that are incompatible with file names. Here is a more complete sample to cleanse this data:

```
string location = page;
foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
{
    location = location.Replace(c, '_');
}
Console.WriteLine(location);
Path.Combine("c:\\temp", location + ".html");
```

Comment: thanks, your response address the underlying problem of invalid file name characters